# Generating a QR code using the NXT / Ardor api for scanning

Tags: nxt, qrcode, ardor

Currently the nxt gui generates a QR code for certain pages where you can scan with your phone or another computer to do an air gap transaction. How can you do this via the api?

Answer (score 1):

https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/The_Nxt_API_Examples#Encode_QR_Code

You can do the following:

```
http://localhost:7876/nxt?
  requestType=encodeQRCode&
  qrCodeData=NXT-7A48-47JL-T7LD-D5FS3&
  width=100&
  height=100
```

Or via the command line:

**curl -d requestType=encodeQRCode -d qrCodeData=NXT-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX -d width=100 -d height=100 http://localhost:7876/nxt**

You can use it in an image tag like this:

*< img src="data:image/gif;base64,**R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAO.....**" width="100" height="100" />*